# Could not locate Razor Host Factory type (ASP.NET WEB MVC )

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web

I have been trying to solve this razor form error for a week now and I can't seem to fix it.

**Packages**:

Microsoft.AspNet.MVC (version 5.2.4)

M.AspNet.Razor (version 3.2.4)

M.AspNet.WebPages (version 3.2.4)

M.Web.Infrastructure (version 1.0.0.0)

Newtonesoft.Json (version 11.0.2)

System.Net.Http (version 4.3.3)

[Packages Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHRZn.png)

HomeController.cs (Code)

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        PrimeCommand PCommand = new PrimeCommand();

        var responseString = await PCommand.Login("user", "pass", "api");
        ViewBag.SessionId = responseString;

        return View();
    }
```

**Login() function:**

```
public async Task<string> Login(string username, string password, string apikey)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler())
            {

                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true; // PJDS code
                using (var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
                {

                    var newLogin = new LoginObject();

                    newLogin.ApplicationKey = apikey;
                    newLogin.UserName = username;
                    newLogin.Password = password;

                    var contentObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newLogin);
                    var content = new StringContent(contentObject);

                    var response = await client.PostAsync(Api.base_url + "/Login", content);
                    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    dynamic responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString);

                    var sessionID = responseObject.result.SessionID;

                    var searchObj = new SimpleSearchObject
                    {
                        SessionID = sessionID
                    };

                    return sessionID;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("error: login - " + e.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
<form style="height: auto;width:300px;" action="action_page.php">
<div class="container">
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
{

   <b>@Html.LabelFor(x => x.UserName)</b>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.UserName)
    <br />

    <b>@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Password)</b>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Password)

    <button type="submit" value="Index" name="action:Index">Login</button>


        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
    </label>
}

    <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
</div>
```

**The Error**

System.InvalidOperationException

Could not locate Razor Host Factory type: 
System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=*******************

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.

Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): System.Web.WebPages.Razor.

Comment: Seriously, someone voted this down and didn't even comment?

Comment: No love, baby. #WereIsTheLove?

Answer (score 1):

I will just answer my question, the problem was in my Web.config file instead of  <....System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.0.0... my version was 5.2.3.0 , I just change the zero to three.

Comment: Hi guys/gals I have another question regarding this, I think I have a problem with my Login() function, because everytime I comment the login function my program works, please help, thank you.

I have this problem:
System.InvalidOperationException
The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.